Universal way to use CommonJS in Javascript with ESM
ESM is the normalized way for module function in Javascript. But there are many CommonJs package in npm.
Vite is good tools for change CommonJs to ESM, I want to use protobufjs in a vue project. The protobufjs in:
https://github.com/protobufjs/protobuf.js/
It works in npm run dev. I want to build it for production environment, following the guide in: https://cn.vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-commonjsoptions
vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    commonjs({
      include: /node_modules/,
    }),
    vue(),
  ]
})

I use it in vue as following:
<script setup>
import * as protobuf from "protobufjs";
console.log(protobuf.Enum)
</script>

Everything is ok when I run the npm run dev. I occurs error in npm run build:
src/App.vue (13:21): "Enum" is not exported by "node_modules/.pnpm/protobufjs@7.4.0/node_modules/protobufjs/index.js", imported by "
src/App.vue".

The example is simple, and config is also. But what result in the error?
Update at 2024/11/12
Vite is a simple tool to use CommonJs, UMD or AMD modules in ESM. It use esbuild in dev and @rollup/plugin-commonjs in prod by default. So we needn't do the config it explicitly.
Thanks for @Estus Flask a lot.

CommonJS modules aren't recognized in ESM environment and require additional module interoperation to work, such as @rollup/plugin-commonjs in Vite/Rollup build. Since Vite has different toolchains for dev and build, there can be discrepancies.
The "universal" way is to use default import. It's less natural for CJS to be translated to * because the export is dynamic, it cannot use ESM traits such as tree-shaking, and can be not just an object but anything.
This is defined by defaultIsModuleExports option, which can be changed if necessary. Transpiled ES modules are automatically recognized by default, this is commonly determined with __esModule property in module object.
Since protobufjs is CJS/UMD module depending on entry point and not transpiled ESM, the correct way to use it:
import protobuf from "protobufjs";

It may be desirable to map entry point to UMD bundle for performance, with the same result expected:
alias: { ..., protobufjs: "protobufjs/dist/protobuf.min.js" }

@rollup/plugin-commonjs isn't needed to be explicitly configured, it's already provided with suitable configuration in Vite default configuration.

Thanks for your answer. I have known the usage of defaultIsModuleExports option and learn more about UMD, CommJs, and ESM. But It also not works for vue and vite. I add the config defaultIsModuleExports:true into vite.config.js for @rollup/plugin-commonjs. And use it as import protobuf from "protobufjs";.

Unfortunately, I got the error again: src/App.vue (7:7): "default" is not exported by "node_modules/.pnpm/protobufjs@7.4.0/node_modules/protobufjs/index.js", imported by "src/App.vue".
It's so strange, beacause the node_modules/.pnpm/@protobufjs+inquire@1.1.0/node_modules/@protobufjs/inquire/index.js has the statement as module.exports = require("./src/index");, so exports is default in ESM. I think @rollup/plugin-commonjs doesn't works finely in vite, is the necessary config  mssing?

Vite already enables the plugin by default, otherwise it would be less usable out of the box. Try to remove  commonjs(), you don't need it, unless you need to provide custom config. defaultIsModuleExports is already set to "auto" by default, so it doesn't need to be changed, it's mentioned because it gives context. I can confirm the package to work. Also I checked, its entry point is modular CJS, you can alias "protobufjs" to protobufjs/dist/protobuf.min.js UMD to make it more efficient

Thanks a lot. I'm sorry that I didn't read the document carefully enough, and takes a lot of trouble for you. I read the document for vite again for the interop of modules.
I learned a lof from you, thanks again!

You're welcome, glad it helped
